# Python: String replacement (replace hyphens with underscores) in all tag names inside an XML

Tags: python, lxml

I have a not-so-well formed XML with hyphens inside the tag names, which I want to replace with underscores (to be able to work with lxml.objectify). I want to replace ALL tag names, including nested childs.

A sample XML:

```
<job>
  <server>
    <cpu-set>
    </cpu-set>
  </server>
  <ip-routings>
  </ip-routings>
</job>
```

I want to convert this XML in a clean way (without regexes but with an XML lib like lxml) to this one:

```
<job>
  <server>
    <cpu_set>
    </cpu_set>
  </server>
  <ip_routings>
  </ip_routings>
</job>
```

What would be a pythonic and clean way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use xpath to find the elements with hyphens and re-write tags:

```
from lxml import etree
data = """<job>
  <server>
    <cpu-set>
    </cpu-set>
  </server>
  <ip-routings>
  </ip-routings>
</job>"""
doc = etree.XML(data)
for e in doc.xpath('//*[contains(local-name(),"-")]'):
  e.tag = e.tag.replace('-','_')

print etree.tostring(doc)
```

Yields:

```
<job>
  <server>
    <cpu_set>
    </cpu_set>
  </server>
  <ip_routings>
  </ip_routings>
</job>
```

Comment: @mac: The OP already said he wanted to use `lxml.objectify`, which is why he needs to convert the hyphens to underscores in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't python, but it is pythonic to me: [C# with the csharp interpreter from mono](http://www.mono-project.com/CsharpRepl):

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

var doc = XDocument.Load(Console.In);

foreach(var node in doc.Descendants().Reverse())
    node.ReplaceWith(new XElement(
        node.Name.Namespace + node.Name.LocalName.Replace("-","_"), 
        node.Attributes(), 
        node.Nodes()));

doc.Save(Console.Out);
```

This has the following important properties that can be hard to do without relying on an existing XML library:

- supports mixed elements (containing text *and* child elements)
- preserves namespaces
- preserves attributes
- supports all XML 2.0 features (CDATA, unparsed, entity references, etc.)
- more like that

#### Demonstration:

input.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<job xmlns:ex="test">
  <server attr1="first" attr2="second">
    <ex:cpu-set>
    </ex:cpu-set>
  </server>
  <ip-routings>
      contained <mixed/>text
  </ip-routings>
</job>
```

Output of `csharp -r:System.Xml.Linq test < input.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<job xmlns:ex="test">
  <server attr1="first" attr2="second">
    <ex:cpu_set />
  </server>
  <ip_routings>
      contained <mixed />text
  </ip_routings>
</job>
```