# Objectify xml string with dashes in tags and attributes names

Tags: python, xml, lxml, lxml.objectify

I am using lxml to objectify xml string with dashes in the tags.

For example:

```
from lxml import objectify
xml_string = """<root>
                   <foo-foo name="example" foo-description="description">
                       <bar doc-name="name" />
                       <test tag="test" />
                    </foo-foo>
                </root>"""
obj = objectify.fromstring(xml_string)
```

After this step, the elements' names come with dashes.
I can't access `foo-foo` due to dashes in the name.

How can I remove dashes from tags name as well as from attribute names?

Comment: what do you want to get from the given xml?

Comment: I want to be able to access foo-foo and its sub-children. For examples
`obj.foo-foo`
and `obj.foo-foo.bar` 
both should be accessible.

Comment: @mzjn That was just an example. I have edited the description now.

Comment: I suspect that this might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2064329/407651

Comment: @mzjn No, this is not relevant as my question is about converting xml string to class object using objectify offered by lxml.

Comment: You've broken your example again; with that example, there are no elements with a `-` because `foo-foo` is the root element. You can access `obj.bar` and `obj.test` and `obj.bar.get('doc-name')` without a problem.

Comment: objectify turns XML elements into object attributes. I think that an attribute called `foo-foo` is problematic.

Comment: ...but note that you *can* access attributes with dashes if you use `getattr` instead of dot notation. E.g., if you had a `bar-bar` element, you could `getattr(obj, 'bar-bar')`

Comment: @larsks I have fixed the xml string again. Now, It contains root element as well.

I see `getattr` as a workaround. I want to access the element with the dot operator. Is there any other way to maybe parse it using XML and then replace `-` characters in the tags in the whole XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hacky, but you could do something like this to transform the `-` in element names to a `_`:

```
from lxml import etree
from lxml import objectify

xml_string = """<root>
                   <foo-foo name="example" foo-description="description">
                       <bar doc-name="name" />
                       <test tag="test" />
                    </foo-foo>
                </root>"""

doc = etree.fromstring(xml_string)
for tag in doc.iter():
    if '-' in tag.tag:
        tag.tag = tag.tag.replace('-', '_')

obj = objectify.fromstring(etree.tostring(doc))
```

In particular, I think there is probably a better way to go from the parsed XML document in `doc` to the objectified version without dumping and reparsing the XML, but this is the best I could come up with on short notice.

Comment: Yes, I think this will work.
I was also thinking on the same line and found the following answer.
[python-string-replacement-replace-hyphens-with-underscores-in-all-tag-names-i](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8324018/python-string-replacement-replace-hyphens-with-underscores-in-all-tag-names-i)

I will accept this is an answer. Thanks @larsks .

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with ElementTree

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

xml = """<foo-foo name="example" foo-description="description">
                   <bar doc-name="name" />
                    <test tag="test" />
                </foo-foo>"""

foo_foo = ET.fromstring(xml)
print(f'name: {foo_foo.attrib["name"]}')
print(f'bar dic name: {foo_foo.find("bar").attrib["doc-name"]}')
print(f'test tag: {foo_foo.find("test").attrib["tag"]}')
```

output

```
name: example
bar dic name: name
test tag: test
```